# Function with zip range

Tags: python, function, printing, while-loop, count

Hello I want to make two counts at once, one incrementing from 0 and another decrementing from 100. The final result should look like this. on the left side it goes from O to 100 incrementing 5, from the right side it goes from 100 to 0 decrementing 7.

```
    0    100
    5    93
   10    86
   15    79
   20    72
   25    65
   30    58
   35    51
   40    44
   45    37
   50    30
   55    23
   60    16
   65     9
   70     2
   75     0
   80     0
   85     0
   90     0
   95     0
  100     0
#What I already have
inc = int(input("ENTER THE INCREMENT NUMBER: "))
dec = int(input("ENTER THE DECREMENT NUMBER: "))

def printcounting(inc, dec):
    for m, n in zip([k for k in range(0, 101, inc)], [l for l in range(100, 0, -dec)]):
        print("{} {}".format(m, n))


printcounting(inc,dec)
```

I want to know how I can print the zeros on the right side, because with the program that I already have it prints depending on the input value. Also I would love to solve it using while instead of the zip function and list.

Comment: OP seems to need `itertools.zip_longest` to pad the shorter generator with zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

`zip` stops when the shorter generator ends so it's not suitable here. A `while` loop would be rather unpythonic here.

You need `itertools.zip_longest` with a zero fill value instead.

You also need to remove the useless list comprehensions which just slow down your program, since they don't filter or transform the data issued by `range`.

```
import itertools

inc = 5
dec = 7

for x in itertools.zip_longest(range(0, 101, inc),range(100, 0, -dec),fillvalue=0):
    print("{} {}".format(*x))
```

result:

```
0 100
5 93
10 86
15 79
20 72
25 65
30 58
35 51
40 44
45 37
50 30
55 23
60 16
65 9
70 2
75 0
80 0
85 0
90 0
95 0
100 0
```

Answer (score 1):

> Also I would love to solve it using while instead of the zip function and list.

Here is a version without using `zip` or `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
In[2]: def print_counting(inc, dec):
  ...:     cnt_1 = 0
  ...:     cnt_2 = 100
  ...:     while True:
  ...:         print('{} {}'.format(cnt_1, cnt_2))
  ...:         if cnt_1 == 100 and cnt_2 == 0:
  ...:             break
  ...:         cnt_1 = min(cnt_1 + inc, 100)
  ...:         cnt_2 = max(cnt_2 - dec, 0)
  ...: 
In[3]: print_counting(5, 7)
0 100
5 93
10 86
15 79
20 72
25 65
30 58
35 51
40 44
45 37
50 30
55 23
60 16
65 9
70 2
75 0
80 0
85 0
90 0
95 0
100 0
```